# Parsing an email with Python

Tags: python, email, parsing

I feel like this is a simple question but nonetheless I cannot find a straightforward answer.

I have an email (an .eml file) that I need to parse. This email has a data table in the body that I need to export to my database. I have been successful parsing data out of txt file emails and attached PDF files, so I understand concepts like mapping to where the data is stored as well as RegularExpressions, but these eml files I can't seem to figure out.

In my code below I have three blocks of code essentially trying to do the same thing (two of them are comments now). I am simply attempting to capture any, or all, of the data in the email. Each block of code produces the same error though:

```
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

I have read that this error is most likely due to Python expecting to receive a string but receives bytes instead, or vice versa. So I followed up those attempts by trying to implement `io.StringIO` or `io.BytesIO` but neither worked. I would like to be able to recognize and parse specific data out of the email.

Thank you for any help, as well as question asking criticism.

My code:

```
import email
#import io
import os
import re

path = 'Z:\\folderwithemlfile'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
if os.path.isfile(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:

        b = email.message_from_string(f)
        if b.is_multipart():
            for paylod in b.get_payload():
                print(payload.get_payload())
        else:
            print(b.get_payload())


        #b = email.message_from_string(f)
        #bbb = b['from']
        #ccc = b['to']


        #print(f)
        #msg = email.message_from_string(f)
        #msg['from']
        #msg['to']
```

Picture of email: 
[image]

Comment: eml file is a proprietary document format from microsoft. You can or cannot parse it with email module, depending on how it is stored. That being said, your issue here is your are passing file object instead of string in here: `email.message_from_string(f)`

Comment: Well, try it yourself. You should replace `email.message_from_string(f)` by `email.message_from_string(f.read())` for a quick try.

Comment: Ohhhh ok... so can I still parse that eml file if I make some adjustments to my code? Or is parsing eml files a whole separate task?

Comment: Try to fix the code. Once it is fixed, you will see whether it can actually parse the file you want or not.

Comment: Well that fix does eliminate the TypeError that kept occurring. But now I am being told `NameError 'payload' is not defined` which should be a simple fix?

Comment: Yeah, you have a typo, `paylod` instead of `payload`

Comment: Wow I'm dumb. I fixed that and now it is printing the data! It's printing the entire email as well as all the extra 100's of lines of HTML characters I think they are... Now that we've confirmed this .eml file can be accessed, I assume it is time to start parsing specific pieces of it? Which might have to wait until tomorrow for me because I'm leaving work momentarily..

Comment: A quick question: can one use RegEx while also using the `email` module? Or is there another better way to capture specific bits of an email?